# Textfield Spacing with "Stretch on Overflow" buggy?

Tags: jasper-reports, overflow, ireport, spacing, stretch

I am currently designing a report using *iReport 4.7.0*. At the moment I am trying to figure out how to dynamically adjust the height of a *textField*, if its contents is too big for the initial height. It seems, that the option ***Stretch on overflow*** achieves this. But I am having problems with that.

If a *textField* is not stretched, the spacing before and after the text is good, because its achieved by setting the *textField* height higher than the font size. But if the *textField* gets dynamically bigger because the containing text is to long to display with the initial height, the lines seem awfully packed, there is no spacing whatsoever.

I tried so resolve this by setting ***Spacing before*** and ***Spacing after*** for the specific *textField* but this seems to end in *JasperReports* thinking, that the *textField* doesn't need to re-size at all, even if the text is not fitting.

Is it possible, that the size created by the ***Spacing before*** and ***Spacing after*** option  is taken into account on calculating, if a *textField* needs to be resized on overflow? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use padding:

1. Right-click an element
2. Select **Padding and Borders**

-or-

1. Right-click an element
2. Select **Show Properties**
3. Click the **Borders** tab
4. Set padding values as required

[image: Example Padding]

This should provide a constant spacing even if box resizes.  For complex layouts, experiment with float position of elements, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412495/stretch-a-row-with-data-overflow-while-having-multiple-rows-in-a-single-band).