# Stretch overflow is not working in Jasper Reports with PrintOrder Horizontal

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Am using `JasperReports` with `Struts2` to generate a pdf of comparision report. Am doing `printOrder="Horizontal"` to show comparision column wise.

In `detail` -

```
<detail>
    <band height="1200">
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Serif_Normal" x="0" y="900" width="369" height="20" positionType="Float"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[$F{PROVFORDRAININGSEDIMENTS}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
             </textField>
        </band>
</detail>
```

But isStretchWithOverflow not working here? texts are still overlapping. is it because printOeder is set to Horizontal?

Comment: Meybe this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412495/stretch-a-row-with-data-overflow-while-having-multiple-rows-in-a-single-band) will help you. I faced the same problem almost a year ago.

Comment: @Rachacha .. Tried with those 4 options but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `printOrder` is set to `Horizontal`, text fields will not stretch. This is because JasperReports strives to align each record across the columns in a report, and allowing them to stretch could cause subsequent data to be misaligned.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. Will try some another way.