# How to show a sentence with line break in report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm new to ireport , and i'm using an xml file in the data source :
and i have this tag in my XML:

```
<paymentType>net upon receipt of invoice.
 Lates fees of 1% monthly will be charged.</paymentType>
```

And i want it in this form after report generation [image]

but after genration in only get this ;

> net upon receipt of

so how to do it (line break ..)?

Comment: i hope below link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml

Comment: put it all on one line and just put multiple spaces in inverted commas between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Your textfield is just not showing all its contents. 
Try to enlarge it manually, or check "stretch with overflow" option in properties of this text field. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412495/stretch-a-row-with-data-overflow-while-having-multiple-rows-in-a-single-band) can be of use to You 
:)