# Jasper iReport, allignment of overflow fields

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, ireport

I need to generate something like this using jasper ireports tool:

```
Address : xyznamexyzcity

          xyzstreetxyz
```

in case the address overflows it should be exactly below the first

Design script is something like this:

```
Address : $F{Address}
```

I tried various possibilities but couldn't get the desired result.

The nearest solution i got is something like this:

```
Address : xyznnamexyzcity

xyzstreetxyw
```

my form is something lke this :

```
name :  $F{}

address : $F{}

city :  $F     , State : $F     , Zip : $F

Phone : $F
```

There is no restriction on length on any of the field

Comment: city and street is samefield or different field

Comment: $f{Address} field contains both city and street

Comment: thanks for the reply, its a single field

Answer (score 0):

This is you want.. Extend the textfield size [REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412495/stretch-a-row-with-data-overflow-while-having-multiple-rows-in-a-single-band)

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: in this case i guess we will get an empty space below, if in case it doesn't overflow

Comment: thanks for the link ganesh. i have tried the same but could achieve only half of the desired result. grouped the fields to be displayed in a single row like this:                                                         "Address    " + $F{VENDOR_ADDR_LINE_1}+"  "+ $F{VENDOR_ADDR_LINE_2}

Comment: after doing so i got the nearest result which i Posted along with the question

Comment: u got me wrong..I got the nearest solution which i posted in the question not the exact desired solution

Answer (score 0):

check strech with overflow

[image: check strech with overflow]

[image]

OUTPUT :-

[image]

---

ANOTHER FIELD:

[image]

OUTPUT :

[image]

Comment: Thanks vikrant, if i enable stretch with overflow , address field is overlapping with the field below it