# IReport text overflows to next detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to get a *TextField* to dynamically size within its band.  When I have more than three rows they overflow into the following detail row.  I tried setting the *Stretch with Overflow*, *Float*, *Relative to Tallest Object*, and *Detail Overflows* to values I saw recommended here.. [Stretch a row with data overflow while having multiple rows in a single band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412495/stretch-a-row-with-data-overflow-while-having-multiple-rows-in-a-single-band)

This did not keep it within it's own band.  I tried in *iReport 5.0.0* and *Eclipse* with *JasperReports* compatible with 5.1.0. The only alternative I have found so far is to make the row bigger but then the bands with fewer rows are too big.
[image]

Note the all caps are supposed to be in the same field.

No luck with Stretch Type RelativeToBandHeight

Comment: Can you post the screenshot to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try set
stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"