# How to create a sum variable in ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports* and *iReport* designer. Now I have table in that I have a column `salary` . So I want to display the sum of all employees salary. 
for that I took a table from pallet created dataset. It displays the table perfectly , in footer I want to display the sum of salary so I created a variable `SalSum` here is the properties of it,

```
class: java.math.BigDecimal
calculation: sum
ResetType:Report
Variable Exp: $F{salary}
```

The problem is , The sum of salary is not displaying and getting the discription as Variable not found:SalSum
and The table also displays 3 times in report how to solve this please help me anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply drag salary field to the footer area.Then it asks field value or result of aggregation function.You have to choose the second option and from there you select the Sum.That's it

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you might not use the correct tag for the sum,

`<textFieldExpression>`

you need to use  for summing inside ireport.

[here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802241/how-do-sum-ireport) is a nice tutorial about how to implement it

Comment: I am not coding anything , I just doing everything from ireport tool

Comment: I have the tag as `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumSal}]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: then the problem might be that the sum enters in a second page? have you checked for this?

Comment: second page means What?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863820/ireport-text-overflows-to-next-detail-band