# Jasper Reports - align dynamic text fields and their labels horizontally

Tags: jasper-reports, alignment, textfield, ireport

I'm using Jasper report 5.2, iReport 5.2 and exporting the report in RTF and PDF formats.

In my report I want to add few text fields along with their (static text)labels aligned horizontally like

```
         Name:  $F{name}
          Age:  $F{age}
Date of Birth:  $F{dateOfBirth}
```

But I'm unable to align them. This is what I tried

- **Position Type:** float (for all static text and fields)
- **Stretch Type:** no stretch (for all static text and fields)
- **Stretch With Overflow:** True (for all dynamic text fields)

The image shows what I get and what I want.
Moreover, my text field's content is dynamic i.e. content size could vary. 
[image]

I've read many forums but could not find a solution, please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It can be easily done with help of container - the *Frame* element.

You should put *Frame* with *Position Type* as **Float** and put to them both *staticText* (label) and *textField*.

For *textField* I've set *Position Type* as **Float** the *Stretch With Overlfow* as **true**.

#### The sample

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="textfields_allign" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d855bf18-5e9b-4060-8caa-3fdd08abce3b">
    <parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="69" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="314bfd5b-7b0a-42f4-aca3-e61f0283f126" positionType="Float" x="213" y="1" width="243" height="20"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="e07201bb-a677-4dc9-a332-f94e6eca2722" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="66c93a44-9015-4ae9-bf05-b68b2420f3ef" positionType="Float" x="121" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="8311a483-955e-4280-a9ac-513d7d34495b" positionType="Float" x="213" y="21" width="243" height="20"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="da404b4e-7908-40ae-8e1b-38e19d9ddc7f" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="e0e312e8-cd2f-48af-8ae8-df95c6195488" positionType="Float" x="121" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="8ff2baf9-b0ec-4c8a-b54a-9edd08b200cc" positionType="Float" x="213" y="41" width="243" height="20"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="b8d97db0-250a-43c8-a2f3-2fa3668c5d15" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="4daa4d17-28be-4ac8-8e1e-2efbeec5f690" positionType="Float" x="121" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

The result will be (via *iReport* preview):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To complete Alex K's solution : with Jaspersoft Studio, do not forget to set the property of the Static Text "stretch type" to "relative to tallest object".

Comment: and if you want skip whole frame if value column is empty -  don't forget to set flag "Remove Line When Blank" and fill "Print When Expression" at frame properties

Answer (score 3):

In Jasper Reports 3.6 and later (including 5.2), there is a facility to use multiple details bands. You can put the first two blocks of **Name** and the text of "Sally Admison ..." in the first band. Below it would be your **Patient ID** and the "1234567890Blah..." and below that would be another details band with **Date of Birth**. This will give you the results that you want.

Do not refer to my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412495/stretch-a-row-with-data-overflow-while-having-multiple-rows-in-a-single-band/10445384?noredirect=1) as this is for the older 3.5 version of Jasper Reports. That version does not allow you to use multiple bands and I had to live with one single details band. This is not the case with 5.2. You can have fun with multiple details bands. Enjoy!

Comment: Though this is not very neat but this solution works and you got me thinking in a different way. For everyone who may face the same problem, the above solution by @Rachcha works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the width of your details pane, that sorted the alignment issues for me.