# strech one field in a frame nove overflowing other frames in a band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 4 frames created in a group header. All the four frames have 2 fields one label and the second value from query. Value filed in all the four frames is set to 'stretch when overflow'=true.
when I run a report when frame 1-value field has huge text it is stretching but the other frames are not moving their position.
Frame 1 is overlapping the frame 2. Frame 2 ,3 and 4 are not changing their position. This is a big report with almost 10 frames.

When frame1- field value is strecheched how to move position of other frames. I tried to set the position to float but it didnot help.

[image]

## Sample:

```
<frame>
    <reportElement style="FrameBorder" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="340" width="1040" height="100">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textField>
        <reportElement key="" style="GroupHeader" x="0" y="0" width="1040" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
        </reportElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{SRUpdateKey}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
        <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="4" y="26" width="1035" height="64">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SR_REPORT_UPDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</frame>
```

Comment: It is better to post the image to illustrate the problem. You should also post small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue

Comment: Looks like duplicate: [Jasper Reports - align dynamic text fields and their labels horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18599795/876298)

Comment: I have added snapshots how data is flowing. Thanks

Comment: Still don't see any jrxml

Comment: didnt see option to attach the file updated the q description with sample and a screen shot too